# Resize images to fit display:flex divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How do I resize an image to fit the display:flex child divs? Please refer to this plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/zqdpqnV7QkKrx7lm1Tsi?p=preview

The image that I am trying to scale is this: http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/8fe/sky-above-the-black-mountains-1402912.jpg

I read on Stackoverflow that this can be done using max-height and max-width attributes but I am unable to achieve the desired result.

I also read this but it doesnt help: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp

CSS:

```
    .card {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 0 0.1rem 0.2rem #aaa;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  margin: 0.5rem 0 1rem 0;
  height: 10rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card.sm {
  height: 10rem;
}

.card.sm .card-action {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.card.md {
  height: 20rem;
}

.card.md .card-action {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.card.lg {
  height: 30rem;
}

.card.lg .card-action {
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

.card .card-content {
  padding: 1rem;
  flex: 8;
  overflow:auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.card .card-content .card-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.card .card-action {
  flex: 2;
  max-height: 5%;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-top: 0.1rem solid rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.2);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.card .card-image {
  position: relative;
  flex: 24;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.card .card-image img {
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="width:30rem">
    <div class="card md">
      <div class="card-image">
        <img src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/8fe/sky-above-the-black-mountains-1402912.jpg"/>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <span class="card-title">Title</span>
        <p>Some content</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <a href="#">ACTION 1</a>
        <a href="#">ACTION 2</a>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <a href="#">ACTION 3</a>
        <a href="#">ACTION 4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="width:30rem">
    <div class="card md">
      <div class="card-content">
        <span class="card-title">Title</span>
        <p>Some content</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <a href="#">ACTION 1</a>
        <a href="#">ACTION 2</a>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <a href="#">ACTION 3</a>
        <a href="#">ACTION 4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Visually what are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: the image that i am display in the card-image div should scale according to the size of the div. if you look at the plunk now, the image is cropped out. i want the whole image to appear in the size of the card-image div

Comment: do you mean http://plnkr.co/edit/h2CZGwqoyJaiAnWeF8fn?p=preview ?

Comment: Hi Gaby. I dont see the complete image in the plunk that you pasted above. The image is being cropped out for some reason

Comment: Check my updated plunk below, you should see the full image as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the height off `.card.md` and `.card` and change `max-width: 100%;` to `width: 100%` on the image.

I have also found that `max-width: 100%` does not work as expected on images within flexbox layouts. I have yet to see (or been able to find) a meaningful reason why, just that "flexbox is new" and browsers don't seem to handle everything as we expect.

Also, bear in mind, you can't have a fixed height on that `.card` and expect the image to fit correctly as the available space will not likely match the proportions of the image. Hence the need for the dynamic height of the `.card` and the dynamic width of the img with `width: 100%;`

Check the updated plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/0CiALVFdKT1uioOjsmZe?p=preview

Comment: thanks. yea it looked like it was an issue with the flex box. removing the height is a big deal for requirements that i have been given. but i guess i ll have to do with replacing that by a min height. thanks for your help. i am going to accept your answer.

Comment: Good deal, glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If I got what you mean, I fixed the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/XiUN82UrnQ4DUXTZrBrA?p=preview).

Basically, you have to delete `overflow:hidden;` from your image and give it a z-index less than the other contents you want over it.

I hope that's what you mean and need.

Comment: thanks AndreaM16. I was looking for what Brian mentioned above but its really cool to know this. thanks again! upvoted your answer.

Comment: No problem, I just misunderstood your real question. Glad you found useful my solution.