# How do I auto-resize an image to fit a 'flex-box' container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How do you auto-resize a large image so that it will fit into a smaller width flex container whilst maintaining its width:height ratio?

Also, the solution must not relate on `vw` / `vh`, so that on a page there can be more in addition to this component.

Here's how it should look like:

[image]

---

Here's my code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
.header {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
.content {
  text-align: center;
}
.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.footer {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Images Are Weird</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="header"></div>
      <div class="content">
       <img class="image" src="https://villagesquare.me/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Facebook-Square.png" alt="square placeholder" />
      </div>
      <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

The solutions I found here do not help

- [How do I auto-resize an image to fit a 'div' container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/how-do-i-auto-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-div-container) (not flex context)
- [Resize images to fit display:flex divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33881457/resize-images-to-fit-displayflex-divs) (fixed size for the image, I need dynamic size)

Answer (score -1):

Just change the **image class** **width** to less than 100% like 50% 60% or 70;

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
.header {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
.content {
  text-align: center;
}
.image {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
.footer {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Images Are Weird</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="header"></div>
      <div class="content">
       <img class="image" src="https://villagesquare.me/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Facebook-Square.png" alt="square placeholder" />
      </div>
      <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also do it by calculating `.content` width and minus as much as you need.like below...

```
.content {
    width:calc(100% - 100px);
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
.header {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
.content {
  width:calc(100% - 100px);
  margin:0 auto;
}
.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.footer {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Images Are Weird</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="header"></div>
      <div class="content">
       <img class="image" src="https://villagesquare.me/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Facebook-Square.png" alt="square placeholder" />
      </div>
      <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: sbrrk, the problem is not that I need horizontal padding around the image. The problem is that it's size doesn't change properly based on the flex container. The image should never take up more width and not more height than it's flex parent, while maintaining it's original width:height ratio.